# Error Message using Quarto on Rstudio when trying to render

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I get this error message when I try to render the quarto doc:

```
Error in `add_html_caption()`:
! unused argument (xfun::grep_sub("^[^<]*<[^>]+aria-labelledby[ ]*=[ ]*\"([^\"]+)\".*$", "\\1", x))
Backtrace:
  1. global .main()
  2. execute(...)
  3. rmarkdown::render(...)
  4. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  5. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
     ...
 14. sew(res, options)
 15. knitr:::sew.list(x, options, ...)
 16. base::lapply(x, sew, options, ...)
 17. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 18. knitr:::sew.knit_asis(x, options, ...)
Execution halted
```

I tried running the entire quarto doc and it runs fine. I also have tried rendering a separate quarto doc which also renders fine. I have restarted R several times as well.

Comment: I ran into the same issue last week. The issue was already reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/pull/5704#issuecomment-1578498455) and could probably be fixed by updating Quarto.